# SQL | Left Join when 2nd Table Has No Matching Row?

Tags: sql, left-join, union-all

I need to be able to show results for a row that doesn't actually exist in a second table. I have tried left join, but it doesn't seem to work for what I need to do. I have 2 tables, for example:

```
Table1
NAME | KEY
John 12345
Frank 23456

Table2
KEY | LIST | STATUS
12345 10001 1
12345 10003 0
23456 10001 1
23456 10002 1
```

I need to be able to show results like this :

```
NAME | KEY | LIST | STATUS
John 12345 10001 1
John 12345 10002 (null)
John 12345 10003 0
Frank 23456 10001 1
Frank 23456 10002 1
Frank 23456 10003 (null)
```

But I can't figure out how to do this because the records that would return a null value don't actually exist in the second table. If I run them one at a time, I can kind of get the results I need by doing a UNION ALL, but this is not efficient (I also had to re-order my results, which is making it harder as well)

```
SELECT b.list, a.name, a.key, b.status
FROM table1 a JOIN table2 b ON a.key = b.key
WHERE a.name = 'John'
UNION ALL
SELECT distinct(b.list), NULL AS "a.name", NULL AS "a.key", NULL AS "b.status"
FROM table2 b
```

This isn't an ideal solution either because I'm pulling the rest of the lists, but the other fields end up being null, so I have to paste them in manually when I move my results to excel.

Any ideas? I really thought I should be able to do this with a left join, but nothing I'm doing seems to work.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Use a `cross join` to get all the rows.  Then use `left join` to bring in the existing values:

```
select t1.key, l.list, t2.status
from table1 t1 cross join
     (select distinct list from table2) l left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.key = t2.key and t1.list = t2.list;
```

Comment: I gave you an upvote, but can you add a little more explanation of what and why you are doing.

Comment: The first sentence is the summary . . . The `cross join` creates all the rows you want, one for each `list` and each `key`.  The `left join` then brings in the data from the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try FULL OUTER JOIN

Example:

```
SELECT A.NAME, A.KEY, A.LIST, B.STATUS
FROM Table1 A 
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 B
ON A.KEY = B.KEY AND A.LIST = B.LIST
```

If don't want rows of the second table that they have not a reference in the first table add the condition:

```
WHERE A.KEY IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with.  The first two queries are used to get all possible combinations of NAME, KEY and LIST together.  The final query joins back to Table2 to get STATUS, returning NULL where STATUS does not exist.

```
;WITH Lists
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT LIST 
    FROM Table2
),
KeyList AS
(
    SELECT [NAME], [KEY],  [LIST]
    FROM Lists CROSS JOIN Table1
)   
SELECT a.[NAME], a.[KEY],A.[LIST],b.[STATUS] 
FROM KeyList a
LEFT JOIN Table2 b
ON a.[KEY] = b.[KEY]
AND a.[LIST] = b.[LIST]
```